# Connect SafeNet HSM using Java remotely

Tags: java, hsm

Our application needs to interact with SafeNet HSM through Luna JSP api using java. We tried the following and were able to connect

```
     LunaSlotManager slotManager = LunaSlotManager.getInstance();
     slotManager.login(password);
```

But my question is that in my program I didn't give any IP Address of the HSM device. Then how does it detect and connect?

Comment: HSM(s) are on-board component; which means you do not connect to them over the network rather connect as a native / local service. Thus no need of IP.

Comment: If So  A network can have single hsm or multiple Hsm. In case of single HSM It can detect hsm associated with network . Is it possible multiple HSM

Comment: @Bond - Java Bond  So all connections under the network in which HSM associated can access HSm or any restriction to this

Comment: HSM instance are mostly one per machine. However keys could be multiple; say one per application.

Comment: IIRC no restrictions to access HSM

Comment: What Luna HSM do you use?

Comment: @Bond-JavaBond You seem to know only PCI HSM's, network HSM's can directly be connected using ethernet adapters. The answer probably lies with the configuration of the underlying PKCS#11 library.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes ok. that is something new for me :) Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any API calls to the Safenet Luna API will interact with the Safenet client software which is installed on your local machine.  This client software handles the actual network connection to the HSM.  The details for which HSM(s) the client software can communicate with are stored in the following locations:

- Windows:  C:\Program Files\LunaSA\crystoki.ini
- Linux, Solaris and AIX:   /etc/Chrystoki.conf

A simple way of listing the active servers is using the vtl command that is part of the Safenet software:

```
$ vtl listservers
Server: 10.10.10.10
```

The vtl command can also be used to make changes to the config files using the addServer and deleteServer commands.